# .NET C# ComboBox default text

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `combobox` populated via `Datasource` and when the application runs it shows the first item instead of the default text setup in the properties.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

The data comes from an API:

```
loteamentos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Loteamento>>(dataObj.Result);
```

and once I have the data, I populate de ComboBox:

```
cb_loteamentos.DataSource = loteamentos;
cb_loteamentos.ValueMember = "id";
cb_loteamentos.DisplayMember = "nome";
```

Comment: How did you add default text for the `ComboxBox`

Comment: @durga In properties, variable 'Text'.

Comment: When you set the DataSource there is no default text to show. You need to search your items for the items that matches your 'default' and the set the SelectedIndex to this item's index

Comment: @un-lucky answer will solve your issue

Comment: @Apalabrados if you want a working solution then you should add the code that sets the DataSource including details on what kind of data is contained in your DataSource

Comment: @Apalabrados - Show us the code, how you are binding your combo and populating it with data source

Comment: If you have a default that matches the name field of your items then just set the Text property to this default after setting the DataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While assigning the DataSource to the comboBox the current associated collection and hence the Default text will be changed. So Assigning default text after assignment of the DataSource will solve your issue:

```
// Bind the combobox
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.Text = "Please select any value";
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want nothing to show (so none of the options from the drop down list) you can set `SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: If the DataSource is set this cannot work... It is impossible to change the items collection when a datasource is set.

Comment: This solution arises an Error. It indicates that Items can not be modified in case it comes from a dataprovider.

Comment: @Steve: thanks for pointing the mistake, have made some updates

Comment: @Apalabrados: could you please check the updates in the answer?

Comment: @un-lucky Many Thanks!!  I worked exactly as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are binding your `combobox` from a data source, it is going to populate the items from the data source and anything set via property pane will be overridden.

You need to add that item as first item in your data source also, to make it appear in combo.

Answer (score -2):

On the form load:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: _when the application runs it shows the first item_ so? what changes with this proposal?

Comment: Oh, I thought he asked for it to show the first item instead of the default text. I can't read

Comment: @Aimnox I suggest you delete this answer to avoid further downvoting or edit it.